# Override Primefaces input components required validation message

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, properties-file

I have the following :

```
<p:inputText id="login"
             value="#{userBean.login}"
             required="true"
             label="Login"
             widgetVar="log">
 <f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
</p:inputText>
```

I need to override the input components message for all jsf required validation.

> default : "Login : erreur de validation. Vous devez indiquer une
>   valeur."
>
> custom : "Login : est requis."

i have already created a properties file in the *com.app.foo* named *Messages* containing the following lines :

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Saisie invalide.
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail = {0}: est requis.
```

Also i have registered it in the **faces-config** with the line below :

```
<message-bundle>
    com.app.foom.Messages
</message-bundle>
```

Yet i still get the default required validation message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mention the attribute `requiredMessage` to inputText component and write custom message.

```
<p:inputText id="login" value="#{userBean.login}" required="true" 
         requiredMessage="est requis" label="Login" widgetVar="log">
    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: tell you waht my friend, that will make do, thank you.